# MediaWiki: Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user)

Tags: php, mediawiki, php-5.6

I have the following error message from MediaWiki, since upgrading to 1.29.2. PHP version: 5.6.32 (cgi-fcgi)

```
Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in [PATH TO]/includes/session/SessionManager.php on line 469
```

Looking at SessionManager.php line 469, I see this line:

`session_write_close();`

in this function:

```
public function shutdown() {
    if ( $this->allSessionBackends ) {
        $this->logger->debug( 'Saving all sessions on shutdown' );
        if ( session_id() !== '' ) {
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
            session_write_close();
        }
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
        foreach ( $this->allSessionBackends as $backend ) {
            $backend->shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Additional info:
PHP version 5.6.32
Linux 2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
session.save_path value: /tmp (this is set to permissions 777)

Comment: Сheck that `tmp` directory is writable for the user and group which your httpd is running on.

 



If you use mod_fastcgi you can see user and group in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fastcgi.conf`.

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase I set /tmp to be 777, the problem still exists

Comment: What name and version of your web server, OS and control panel? Have you changed the user and group for tmp directory?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase I added some context